# How to implement whole-provider-process synchronization on a custom plugin

Tags: terraform

I created a custom terraform provider for managing various network related resources (dhcp, dns, ip address) for a product called Solarwinds Orion.

I'm having issues with the API where I will obtain duplicate resources if request is close toghether.

I have tried adding a wait to the API request.

Comment: Do you mean the Soarwinds Orion API? If so, this sounds like an issue for Solarwinds Orion. Wouldn't that be considered a bug?

Comment: [In this comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7631#issuecomment-407896388) @apparentlymart mentions whole-provider-synchonization. I agree this may be considered a bug. But I would like to see if I can make up for this with terraform.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone developing a custom provider where the API has rate limiting or running into race conditions:

Golang `Mutex` will allow you to lock the process from running, Terraform has included it in its SDK. More information in this forum post.

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/whole-provider-process-synchronization/2006